# Array out of bond exception while reading files

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

could you help me.. I need a simple program to preprocess some data to datamining and i´m trying to do this in java but it´s give array out of bond exception, could you help me fixing it? thanks.

The task is really simple, just read two files and write a third with the information required.

```
        try {
            while ((linhapessoa = pessoain.readLine())!= null)
            {
                String[] splitlinhapessoa = linhapessoa.split(",");
                String pessoaId = splitlinhapessoa[1] + splitlinhapessoa[2] + splitlinhapessoa[3] + splitlinhapessoa[4]
                + splitlinhapessoa[23];
                String domclId = splitlinhapessoa[1] + splitlinhapessoa[2] + splitlinhapessoa[3] + splitlinhapessoa[4];

                while ((linhaconsumo = consumoin.readLine())!= null)
                {
                 String[] splitlinhaconsumo = linhaconsumo.split(",");
                 String con_pessoaId = splitlinhaconsumo[1] + splitlinhaconsumo[2] + splitlinhaconsumo[3] +
                 splitlinhaconsumo[4] + splitlinhaconsumo[21]  ;
                 String con_domclId = splitlinhaconsumo[1] + splitlinhaconsumo[2] + splitlinhaconsumo[3] + splitlinhaconsumo[4];




                 if (pessoaId.equals(con_pessoaId))
                 {
                    if (((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "801"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "1101"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "1301"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "28") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "2401"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "28") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "2402")))
                       {cons_celular = "1"; val_cons_celular = splitlinhaconsumo[11];}

                    if (((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "801"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "901"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "1101"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "1401"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "401"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "501")))
                       {cons_telfixo = "1"; val_cons_telfixo = splitlinhaconsumo[11];}

                    if ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "28") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "1101"))
                    {
                    cons_shows = "1"; val_cons_shows = splitlinhaconsumo[11];
                    }

                    if (((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "13") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "1701"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "15") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "2701"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "28") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "5701"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "28") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "2601"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "28") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "901")))                      
                       {cons_dvd = "1"; val_cons_dvd = splitlinhaconsumo[11]; }

                     if (((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") && (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "502"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "503"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "504"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "505"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "506"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "801"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "901"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "1001"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "1301"))|
                       ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "6") &&  (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "1401")))                      
                       {cons_internet = "1"; val_cons_internet = splitlinhaconsumo[11];  }

                     if ((splitlinhaconsumo[9] == "28") && (splitlinhaconsumo[10] == "101"))
                     {cons_cinema = "1"; val_cons_cinema = splitlinhaconsumo[11];  }




                     String linhasaida = linhapessoa + ","  + cons_celular + "," + val_cons_celular + "," + cons_telfixo+ "," + val_cons_telfixo +
                     "," + cons_shows + "," + val_cons_shows + "," +  cons_dvd + "," + val_cons_dvd + "," + cons_internet + "," + val_cons_internet
                             + "," + cons_cinema + "," + val_cons_cinema;

                     processado.write(linhasaida);

                }
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error message and stack trace? Can you reproduce the problem with a smaller code sample?

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==`. And show us a [mcve]. Going through a huge wall fo code is annoying.

Comment: 'While reading files' has nothing to do with it. Keep it relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java (as in most, but not all languages) are 0 indexed.

So your first column is 0, not 1.